# Create a group id in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have data in this format

[image]

| ColA | Date | RSN | ID | DesiredColumn |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 70 | 0904 | 2 | 0904-2 | 1 |
| 71 | 0904 | 3 | 0904-3 | 1 |
| 100 | 0904 | 4 | 0904-4 | 1 |
| 70 | 0904 | 5 | 0904-5 | 2 |

I want to add the DesiredColumn that changes its values every time it sees RTI = 070 in ColA

Can someone please help?

Comment: Images of data (let alone hyperlinks to images) don't help us help you. Take the time to post the data in a consumable format; preferably DDL and DML statements but at least as well formatted tabular `text`. Don't forget to explain your problem in detail, and demonstrate *your* attempts.

Comment: This is a simple Gap and Island query, you need to be explicit on the sort sequence, but pretty easy with a LAG function

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I tried to take a look at it but am unable to crack the problem. Any assistance? I edited the question to add sample data

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a cumulative sum, something like:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when colA = 70 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by date order by rsn)
from t;
```

I am guessing that you want this per value of date and the ordering is based on `rsn`.  If that is not true, remove the `partition by` clause.

Sql Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/59e49/10

Comment: Works like a charm !! Thank you so much. So elegant and simple